# Ingresar una cadena de texto en Python y dar salto de línea con determinado valor

Tags: python, while

Tengo este código que esta dando un error constante que no se como solucionar y además de eso al ejecutar el if no da el resultado que debería. Básicamente lo que quiero es que cuando algún valor especifico se encuentre en un input se haga un salto de línea pero no consigo que lo haga.

Cualquier ayuda la agradezco mucho, ya estoy super frustrado con esto.

```
import time
import os

msg = "Introduzca un poema: "

poema = ""
while True:
  txt = input(msg)

  if len(txt.strip) == 0:
    print("Intruzca un poema valido")
    time.sleep(5)
    os.system("cls")
    continue

  if "<enter>" in txt:
    txt.replace("<enter>", "\n")
    poema += txt
    
  if "@" in txt:
    txt.replace("@", "\nFin del Poema")
    poema += txt
    break

print(poema)
```

Comment: ¿Qué resultado debería dar el if? ¿cual "valor específico"? Es mejor que pongas ejemplos concretos y no vagas descripciones.

Comment: Que cada vez que se encuentre "<enter>" o "@" se haga un salto de linea tal y como está en el codigo, solo que nose porque el codigo no hace lo que está.

Comment: `txt.replace()` no cambia lo que hay en la variable `txt` sino que crea una nueva cadena con el texto reemplazado y te la devuelve. Ya que no la asignas a ninguna variable se pierde. Puedes hacer  `txt = txt.replace(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Hice algunas modificaciones que creo podrían funcionarte mejor.

Lo que hacia el "while True" lo mejore con una condición y modifique el input, el timer que daba 5 segundos y algunas cosas mas.

```
msg = str(input("Introduzca un poema: "))
poema = ""
while len(msg) == 0:
  print("Intruzca un poema valido")
  msg = str(input("Introduzca un poema: "))


if "<enter>" in msg:
  msg = msg.replace("<enter>", "\n")
  poema = str(msg)

if "@" in msg:
  msg = msg.replace("@", "\n")
  poema = str(msg)

if "|" in msg:
  msg = msg.replace("|", "\nFin del Poema")
  poema = str(msg)
```

Ahora solo queda hacer el print:

```
print(poema)

# Podes poner enter o @ para el salto de linea y cuando quieras dar el final cortas con "|"
```

Contame que tal te fue. Saludos.

Comment: Mi idea fue sin alterarle totalmente el código hacer que le funcione y que pueda hacer modificación de una manera sencilla. Ahí puede visiblemente agregar o quitar otros caracteres de corte a su gusto. Podría haber hecho el código completamente desde cero pero creo que no le hubiese servido.